# convert various date formats to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to convert various date formats to a single format, i.e.to yyyy-mm-dd , so for example:

```
20-10-1975 -> 1975-10-20 (dd-mm-yyyy -> yyyy-mm-dd) 

01-25-1961 ->1961-01-25 (mm-dd-yyyy -> yyyy-mm-dd) 

1991-10-25 -> 1991-10-25 (yyyy-mm-dd remains yyyy-mm-dd)
```

if possible also with the time component, so for example:

```
20-10-1975 13:15:22 -> 1975-10-20 13:15:22
```

The reason is I want to be able to sort an array on dates, but sometimes I have to deal with various formats which I don't control.

Is there a function to achieve this?

PS I am aware that sometime a date can be ambiguous, for example 6-5-2015 can be 6th of May, or 5th of June, but I am fine with this as long as the sorting works.

Comment: To sort date, split on delimiter, rearrange and sort in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss order. No need for library

Comment: Can you have a uniform date format?

Comment: How do you want to handle `06-07-2008`?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat). It may help you but having never used it, I cannot help you with this.

For simple cases, you can do it manually with the help of strings' [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
You will have to implement your parser for each different format you want to use though.
Here is a simple example. I chose to pass by a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to make parsing and formatting independent but you may choose to just reorder the parts.

```js
function parse(dateString){
  var parts = dateString.split("-");
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
}

function format(date){
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var day = date.getDay();
  return [
    date.getFullYear(),
    month > 9 ? month : "0" + month,
    day > 9 ? day : "0" + day
  ].join("-");  
}

var date = parse("20-10-1975");
console.log(format(date));
```

However, I would recommend to use a library which can save you some time and give you greater flexibility at the cost of an additional dependency.
One of the most famous libraries to manipulate dates, for example, is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).
Here is an example how you can use it.

```js
var ex1 = moment("20-10-1975", "DD-MM-YYYY")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(ex1);

var ex2 = moment("01-25-1961", "MM-DD-YYYY")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(ex2);

var ex3 = moment("1991-10-25", "YYYY-MM-DD")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(ex3);

var ex4 = moment("20-10-1975 13:15:22", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
  .format("YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss");
console.log(ex4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to try to match to multiple formats (as it seems to be your case), you can also do this. Just provide the order at which `momentjs` should try to recognise your string.
Here is an example.

```js
function formatDate(dateStr, inputFormats, outputFormat){
  // Format without the hours, minutes and seconds.
  inputFormats = inputFormats || [
    "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "DD-MM-YYYY",
    "MM-DD-YYYY"
  ];
  outputFormat = outputFormat || "YYYY-MM-DD";
  
  // Try to match without the hours, minutes and seconds.
  var mDate = moment(dateStr, inputFormats, true);
  if(mDate.isValid()){
    // If that worked, give the result without them.
    return mDate.format(outputFormat);
  }
  
  // Create format with hours, minutes and seconds.
  var extendedInputFormats = inputFormats.map(function(f){
    return f + " HH:mm:ss";
  });
  // Try to match with hours, minutes and seconds.
  mDate = moment(dateStr, extendedInputFormats, true);
  if(mDate.isValid()){
    // If that worked, give the result with them.
    return mDate.format(outputFormat + " HH:mm:ss");
  }
}

console.log("20-10-1975 =>", formatDate("20-10-1975"));
console.log("01-25-1961 =>", formatDate("01-25-1961"));
console.log("1991-10-25 =>", formatDate("1991-10-25"));
console.log("20-10-1975 13:15:22 =>", formatDate("20-10-1975 13:15:22"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To sort date, split on delimiter, rearrange and sort in yyyy-mm-dd order. No need for a library

Comment: Hi; thanks for the reply; but those examples assume the initial date-format is known already, right? The way I would like it is if the initial format doesn't need to be included in the function.

Comment: Yes. But how would you make the difference between "2014-10-10" with first 10 being a month and "2014-10-10" with first 10 being a day without specifying a format?

Comment: A spilt and a re-order with test if the assumed month is <=12 is not inventing the wheel

Comment: No actual need to create a date to sort

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that for simple cases doing it manually is sufficient. But it feels like OP's case required the support of multiple different format. Except if using a library is really a problem (moment is 14kb), I don't see why one should worry about coding himself what is already out there and works fine.

Comment: @mplungjan I created a date in my example to make the decoding independent from the coding and vice-versa. Though it is just an example to show what is possible.

Comment: @user2022678 I made an update to my answer with an example using the multiple format capabilities of `momentjs`. Using it, you should manage to achieve what you are looking for.